# F# type class persistent counter

Tags: class, f#, counter

Gentlefolk,

Old time procedural/deterministic programmer battling with F# functional....

I require some counters to record counts from various areas of a program.
The following code compiles clean and appears to work but "ctr" is never incremented.

Any help appreciated, Ian

```
type Count() as this = 
    let mutable ctr = 0
    do
        printfn "Count:Constructor: %A" ctr
    member this.upctr : int = 
        let ctr  = ctr + 1 
        printfn "inCount.upctr %d" ctr
        ctr

let myCount = new Count()
printfn "MyCtr1 %d" (myCount.upctr)
let fred = myCount.upctr
let fred = myCount.upctr
```

Comment: Just to explain what happens in your code: `let ctr = ctr + 1` does not reference the mutable `ctr` variable, but instead creates a *new* variable with the same name that *shadows* the old `ctr` variable. Hence this line always creates a new `ctr` using the old `ctr` of value `0` and adds `1` to it.

Answer (score 5):

You could also create a threadsafe counter like this:

```
let counter() =
    let c = ref 0
    fun () ->
        System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(c)
```

and use

```
let countA = counter()
let countB = counter()
countA() |> printfn "%i" // 1
countA() |> printfn "%i" // 2
countB() |> printfn "%i" // 1
```

Wrap this in a type or module, if needed.

Comment: I always prefer this type of design when dealing with mutable state in F#, even if thread-safety is not a concern, because it keeps the mutable state from being exposed.  Nothing else can possibly mutate the counter value here, because it is only available inside the closure.

Answer (score 3):

The value `ctr` is mutable. Use:

```
ctr  <- ctr + 1  // this will mutate the value contained in ctr
```

instead of

```
// this will create a new binding which is not mutable
// and will shadow the original ctr
let ctr = ctr + 1
```

Also notice the warning that is telling you that you don't need  `as this` in the type declaration.

Comment: I have tried "ctr <- ctr + 1" the compiler throws an error "unexpected symbol.....". Ian.

Comment: If you replace it in the code exactly as it is right now (in your question) it will work.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Simply replaced the "=" with "<-" and still get the unexpected symbol.

Comment: My environment is Linux Mint 18.2, MonoDevelop 7.1, .Net/F# V4.5.1.

Comment: "Simply replaced the "=" with "<-""  No, read carefully, it's not just the operator. Remove the `let` as well.

Comment: Gustavo, thanks, there are none so blind...... Removed the "let", a different error - on "member upctr". Error is "The instance member needs a parameter.....". This can be addressed by applying "as this and then this.upctr" but then the warning "The recursive object reference...." occurs on the "type count() as this =".

Comment: OK, that was the problem. What you see now is a different issue, nothing to do with this.Maybe post the full code in another question for those errors.